# What produces "finished with non-zero exit value 1"?

Tags: android, error-handling, android-xml, android-drawable

I am trying to use aliases to reference `drawables` in my `XML` files, and the first one is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/portrait_a_3" />
```

The file is named `portrait_a.xml`, stored in a `drawable-sw320dp-xhdpi`. It refers to a file in the `drawable-nohdpi` and works fine. However, when I add a second file (in the same folder), that's identical save the "a" in both the referenced file's name as well as the new file's file name is replaced by "b", I get:

```
Execution failed for task':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Developer/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt" finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Why and how do I fix it? It feels like I've forgot something basic, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out clean and rebuild makes it work.